# Suggesting for my book's Blurb

Tags: fiction, novel

I am working on my upcoming book's blurb. One of my characters is a leader inspired by Hitler. I have mentioned him as "Hitler like leader".

But this seems weak in my blurb. What can I write to convey that he is a leader like Hitler?

Comment: Maybe "Hitler is back." Would work better in your attempt at exploiting the brand. Imho you'd be better off without referring to such grim moments of human history. For instance "a bloodlusting master of conspiracy has set his eyes on {something} and will enslave millions to achieve it. His dictatorship will not vanish unnoticed."

Answer (score 4):

Focus on how he's "like Hitler", is he a totalitarian dictator, did he sweep to power by temporarily allying himself with the latest political fad before showing his true colours, does he lose a war he could have won simply by concentrating on one thing at a time because he had no patience as a military strategist, is it just that he's a tee-total vegetarian, or does he draw direct inspiration from Hitler's various accomplishments and eccentricities? Be specific about where he overlaps with the historical figure you are choosing to compare him to, and use that to convey his "Hitler-ness" both in the blurb and in the story as a whole.

Comment: He spread lies to convince people.

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy - with all due respect, that isnt a particularly "Hitler-ish" trait, that is just called being a politician

Comment: There are some other similarities as well, like capturing people of different class etc.